# displace an element in array by sum

Tags: ruby

I am trying to displace an array by adding a value to every element and then adding those new values to the array (array are x,y,z > sketchup) example:

```
arr = [[2.99213, 0, 0],
       [2.93025, 0.0031909, 0],
       [2.86903, 0.0127298, 0],
       [2.80912, 0.0285154, 0]]
```

Adding **2** to every first element to get this:

```
arr = [[4.99213, 0, 0],
       [4.93025, 0.0031909, 0],
       [4.86903, 0.0127298, 0],
       [4.80912, 0.0285154, 0]]
```

finally, adding the two arrays:

```
arr = [[2.99213, 0, 0],
       [2.93025, 0.0031909, 0],
       [2.86903, 0.0127298, 0],
       [2.80912, 0.0285154, 0],
       [4.99213, 0, 0],
       [4.93025, 0.0031909, 0],
       [4.86903, 0.0127298, 0],
       [4.80912, 0.0285154, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
arr = [[2.99213, 0, 0], [2.93025, 0.0031909, 0], [2.86903, 0.0127298, 0], [2.80912, 0.0285154, 0]]
arr + arr.map { |k| [k[0]+2] + k[1..-1] }

# => [[2.99213, 0, 0], [2.93025, 0.0031909, 0], [2.86903, 0.0127298, 0], [2.80912, 0.0285154, 0], [4.9921299999999995, 0, 0], [4.93025, 0.0031909, 0], [4.86903, 0.0127298, 0], [4.80912, 0.0285154, 0]]
```

Comment: `arr + arr.map { |e, *rest| [e + 2, *rest] }`

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, I solved it using the api inside sketchup, I need it to work with vectors, of course where talking about x,y,z points my mistake....thanks for all your help anyway.....